# Main font of the fontspec package interfering with the escapechar in the listings environment

Tags: listings, fontspec

**Output Before Setting Main Font**

Before setting the main font using the fontspec package, the `escapechar` was working properly. Below is the output picture:
[image: Output before setting the main font]
and below is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{bigfoot} % to allow verbatim in footnote
\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}
\let\ph\mlplaceholder % shorter macro
\lstMakeShortInline"

\lstset{
    style              = Matlab-editor,
    basicstyle         = \mlttfamily,
    escapechar         = ",
    mlshowsectionrules = true,
}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{lstlisting}[caption = {For educational purposes}]
        % example of while loop using placeholders
        while "\ph{condition}"
        if "\ph{something-bad-happens}"
        break
        else
        % do something useful
        end
        % do more things
        end
    \end{lstlisting}
    
\end{document}
```

**Output After Setting Main Font**

After setting the Times New Roman as my main font, the `escapechar` are now appearing as open boxes, which is something I do not like. Below is the output picture:
[image: Output after setting the main font]
and below is my MWE:

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{bigfoot} % to allow verbatim in footnote
\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}
\let\ph\mlplaceholder % shorter macro
\lstMakeShortInline"

\lstset{
    style              = Matlab-editor,
    basicstyle         = \mlttfamily,
    escapechar         = ",
    mlshowsectionrules = true,
}
\usepackage{fontspec}% added
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{lstlisting}[caption = {For educational purposes}]
        % example of while loop using placeholders
        while "\ph{condition}"
        if "\ph{something-bad-happens}"
        break
        else
        % do something useful
        end
        % do more things
        end
    \end{lstlisting}
    
\end{document}
```

How do I get the proper `escapechar` in the presence of the main font?

Comment: as the log files says `Missing character: There is no 〈 (U+2329) in font TimesNewRoman:mode=node`. You could try e.g. TeX Gyre Termes instead.

Comment: Is not there any way or alternative using Times New Roman as my main font?

Comment: you can probably redefine \phClDelim@mlpr and \phOpDelim@mlpr to use some other symbol, or switch the font.

Comment: Can you please assist with redefining `\phClDelim@mlpr` and `\phOpDelim@mlpr`? My document requires me to use the Times New Roman as the main font.

Comment: Do: `\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\phOpDelim@mlpr{$\langle$}
\renewcommand\phClDelim@mlpr{$\rangle$}
\makeatother`

Comment: Thank you very much @Cicada. It worked perfectly! I suggest that you add your comment as an answer so that you earn your deserved reputation.

Comment: Alternatively. find a font with the angle bracket symbols, e.g., FreeSans, and do: `\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontface\fontangles{FreeSans}
\renewcommand\textlangle{{\fontangles 〈}}
\renewcommand\textrangle{{\fontangles 〉}}`.

Comment: Thank you very much @Cicada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`matlab-prettifier` package is using the (text version of the math) symbols `〈` and `〉` as delimiters in its `\placeholder` command.

```
\newcommand\mlplaceholder[1]
{%
...   \phOpDelim@mlpr%
...    #1
...   \phClDelim@mlpr%
}
```

with the delimiter macros being defined as:

```
\newcommand\phOpDelim@mlpr{\textlangle}
\newcommand\phClDelim@mlpr{\textrangle}
```

Times New Roman does not have those symbols.

A math font, like `Asana-Math`, has them, but we want to keep Times New Roman.

The default math mode fonts in latex also have them, so we can redefine the delimiters to use the math version instead of the text companion version:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\phOpDelim@mlpr{$\langle$}
\renewcommand\phClDelim@mlpr{$\rangle$}
\makeatother
```

Or, alternatively, we can use those symbols from another (Unicode) font which has them, `FreeSans` say. We leave the matlab commands unchanged as original, and instead redefine `\textlangle` and `\textrangle` directly:

```
\newfontface\fontangles{FreeSans}
\renewcommand\textlangle{{\fontangles 〈}}
\renewcommand\textrangle{{\fontangles 〉}}
```

Alternatively again, using a legacy font, those symbols are in slots 60 and 62 of the TS1 encoding scheme:

```
\newcommand\mytextlangle{{\usefont{TS1}{cmr}{m}{n}\char60}}
\newcommand\mytextrangle{{\usefont{TS1}{cmr}{m}{n}\char62}}
```

[image: angle brackets]

MWE

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{bigfoot} % to allow verbatim in footnote
\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}
\let\ph\mlplaceholder % shorter macro
\lstMakeShortInline"

\lstset{
    style              = Matlab-editor,
    basicstyle         = \mlttfamily,
    escapechar         = ",
    mlshowsectionrules = true,
}
\usepackage{fontspec}% added
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontface\fontangles{FreeSans}
\renewcommand\textlangle{{\fontangles 〈}}
\renewcommand\textrangle{{\fontangles 〉}}
%\makeatletter
%\renewcommand\phOpDelim@mlpr{$\langle$}
%\renewcommand\phClDelim@mlpr{$\rangle$}
%\makeatother
\newcommand\mytextlangle{{\usefont{TS1}{cmr}{m}{n}\char60}}
\newcommand\mytextrangle{{\usefont{TS1}{cmr}{m}{n}\char62}}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{lstlisting}[caption = {For educational purposes}]
        % example of while loop using placeholders
        while "\ph{condition}" 
        if "\ph{something-happens}"
        break 
        else
        % do something useful
        end
        % do more things
        end
    \end{lstlisting}

legacy:  \mytextlangle x\mytextrangle

\end{document}
```

Note that `fontspec` is indeed working perfectly, and the escape character is also working perfectly. Any font not having those symbols will produce the same effect as Times New Roman.

Comment: This is an excellent solution @Cicada. All the solutions worked out perfectly!